# How to setup Virtualbox Ubuntu VM for External Remote Connection

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I made a Virtualbox VM and installed the latest version of Ubuntu desktop. I'd like to set it up so I have the VM running on my local machine at home, and be able to connect to it via RDP.

I setup screenshare on the VM itself, and with Virtualbox. My question is, how do I make it so I can connect to the VM outside of my local network? Right now I am only able to connect to it by typing in the IP:3389 into my browser.

Thank you for any and all help.